# Grammatical Framework: "linearization type field cannot be Int"; how to write a concrete syntax for grammar with arithmetic expressions?

Tags: gf

I'm trying to write a concrete syntax for this grammar (from Chapter 6 in [Grammatical Framework: Programming with Multilingual Grammars](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/gf-book/)):

```
abstract Arithm = {
  flags startcat = Prop ;
  cat
    Prop ;                        -- proposition
    Nat ;                         -- natural number
  fun
    Zero : Nat ;                  -- 0
    Succ : Nat -> Nat ;           -- the successor of x
    Even : Nat -> Prop ;          -- x is even
    And  : Prop -> Prop -> Prop ; -- A and B
}
```

There are predefined categories for integer, float and string literals (`Int`, `Float` and `String`), and they can be [used as arguments to functions](https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2018/12/05/literals.html), but they may not be value types of any function.

In addition, they may not be used as a field in a linearisation type. This is what I would like to do, using `plus` [defined in Predef.gf](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/blob/master/src/prelude/Predef.gf#L27):

```
concrete ArithmEng of Arithm =
  open Predef, SymbolicEng, SyntaxEng, ParadigmsEng in
  lincat
    Prop = S ;
    Nat  = {s : NP ; n : Int} ;
  lin
    Zero     = mkNat 0 ;
    Succ nat = let n' : Int = Predef.plus nat.n 1 in mkNat n' ;
    Even nat = mkS (mkCl nat.s (mkA "even")) ;
    And p q  = mkS and_Conj p q ;
  oper
    mkNat  : Int -> Nat ;
    mkNat int = lin Nat {s = symb int ; n = int} ;
} ;
```

But of course, this does not work: I get the error "linearization type field cannot be Int".

Maybe the right answer to my question is to use another programming language, but I am curious, because this example is left as an exercise to the reader in the GF book, so I would expect it to be solvable.

I can write a unary solution, using the category `Digits` from `Numeral.gf`:

```
concrete ArithmEng of Arithm =
  open SyntaxEng, ParadigmsEng, NumeralEng, SymbolicEng, Prelude in {
  lincat
    Prop = S ;
    Nat = {s : NP ; d : Digits ; isZero : Bool} ;
  lin
    Zero = {s = mkNP (mkN "zero") ; d = IDig D_0 ; isZero = True} ;
    Succ nat = case nat.isZero of {
                 True  => mkNat (IDig D_1) ;
                 False => mkNat (IIDig D_1 nat.d) } ;
    Even nat = mkS (mkCl nat.s (mkA "even")) ;
    And p q  = mkS and_Conj p q ;
  oper
    mkNat : Digits -> Nat ;
    mkNat digs = lin Nat {s = symb (mkN "number") digs ; d = digs ; isZero = False} ;
} ;
```

This produces the following results:

```
Arithm> l -bind Even Zero
zero is even

0 msec
Arithm> l -bind Even (Succ Zero)
number 1 is even

0 msec
Arithm> l -bind Even (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))
number 111 is even
```

This is of course a possible answer, but I suspect this is not the way the exercise was intended to be solved. So I wonder if I'm missing something, or if the GF language used to support more operations on Ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible, but still rather unsatisfactory answer, is to use the parameter `Ints n` for any natural number `n`.

Notice the difference:

- `Int` is a [literal type](https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2018/12/05/literals.html), just like `String` and `Float`.
- All [literals have `{s : Str}` as their lincat](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/blob/master/src/prelude/PredefCnc.gf#L2-L3) in every concrete syntax, and you can't change it in any way.
- Since the lincat contains `Str` ([not String](https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2018/12/05/literals.html#string-vs-str)), you are not allowed to [pattern match it at runtime](https://inariksit.github.io/gf/2018/08/28/gf-gotchas.html#unsupported-token-gluing).

#### Introducing `Ints n`: a parameter type

However, `Ints n` is a parameter type, because it's finite.
You may have seen `Ints n` in old RGL languages, like the following [Finnish grammar](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/blob/master/src/finnish/MorphoFin.gf#L363-L379):

```hs
-- from the Finnish resource grammar
oper
  NForms : Type = Predef.Ints 10 => Str ;

  nForms10 : (x1,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,x10 : Str) -> NForms =
    \ukko,ukon,ukkoa,ukkona,ukkoon,
       ukkojen,ukkoja,ukkoina,ukoissa,ukkoihin -> table {
    0 => ukko ;   1 => ukon ;    2 => ukkoa ;
    3 => ukkona ; 4 => ukkoon ;  5 => ukkojen ;
    6 => ukkoja ; 7 => ukkoina ; 8 => ukoissa ;
    9 => ukkoihin ; 10 => ukko
    } ;
```

What's happening here? This is an inflection table, where the left-hand side is… just numbers, instead of combinations of case and number. (For instance, `5` corresponds to plural genitive. Yes, it is completely unreadable for anyone who didn't write that grammar.)

That same code could as well be written like this:

```hs
-- another way to write the example from the Finnish RG
param
  NForm = SgNom | SgGen | … | PlGen | PlIll ; -- Named params instead of Ints 10
oper
  NForms : Type = NForm => Str ;

  nForms10 : (x1,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,x10 : Str) -> NForms =
    \ukko,ukon,ukkoa,ukkona,ukkoon,
       ukkojen,ukkoja,ukkoina,ukoissa,ukkoihin -> table {
    SgNom => ukko ; 
    SgGen => ukon ;
    ...
    PlGen => ukkojen ;
    PlIll => ukkoihin
    } ;
```

As you can see, the integer works as a left-hand side of a list: `5 => ukkojen` is as valid GF as `PlGen => ukkojen`. In that particular case, `5` has the type `Ints 10`.

Anyway, that code was just to show you what `Ints n` is and how it's used in other grammars than mine, which I'll soon paste here.

#### Step 1: incrementing the Ints

Initially, I wanted to use `Int` as a field in my lincat for `Nat`. But now I will use `Ints 100` instead. I linearise `Zero` as `{n = 0}`.

```hs
concrete ArithmC of Arithm = open Predef in {
  lincat
    Nat = {n : Ints 100} ;
  lin
    Zero = {n = 0} ; -- the 0 is of type Ints 100, not Int!
```

Now we linearise also `Succ`. And here's the exciting news: we can use `Predef.plus` on a *runtime value*, because the runtime value is no longer on `Int`, but `Ints n`---which is finite! So we can do this:

```hs
  lin
    Succ x = {n = myPlus1 ! x.n} ;

  oper
    -- We use Predef.plus on Ints 100, not Int
    myPlus1 : Ints 100 => Ints 100 = table {
      100 => 100 ;           -- Without this line, we get error
      n => Predef.plus n 1   -- magic!
      } ;
}
```

As you can see from `myPlus1`, it's definitely possible to pattern match `Ints n` at runtime. And we can even use the `Predef.plus` on it, except that we must cap it at the highest value. Without the line `100 => 100`, we get the following error:

```
- compiling ArithmC.gf... Internal error in GeneratePMCFG:
    convertTbl: missing value 101
                among 0
                      1
                      ...
                      100
```

Unfortunately, it's restricted to a finite `n`.

Let's test this in the GF shell:

```
$ gf
…

> i -retain ArithmC.gf 

> cc Zero
{n = 0; lock_Nat = <>}

> cc Succ Zero
{n = 1; lock_Nat = <>}

> cc Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))
{n = 5; lock_Nat = <>}
```

Technically works, if you can say that. But we can't do anything interesting with it yet.

#### Step 2: Turn the `Ints n` into a `NP`

Previously, we just checked the values in a GF shell with `cc` ([compute_concrete](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/doc/tutorial/gf-tutorial.html#toc42)). But the whole task for the grammar was to produce sentences like "2 is even".

The lincat for `Int` (and all literal types) is `{s : Str}`. To make a literal into a `NP`, you can just use [the Symbolic module](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis/index.html#toc128).

But we cannot increment an `Int` at runtime, so we chose to use `Ints 100` instead.

But there is no lincat for `Ints n`, because it's a `param`. So the only way I found is to manually define a `showNat` oper for `Ints 100`.

This is ugly, but technically it works.

```hs
concrete ArithmEng of Arithm =
  open Predef, SymbolicEng, SyntaxEng, ParadigmsEng in {
  lincat
    Prop = S ;
    Nat  = {s : NP ; n : MyInts} ;
  oper
    MyInts = Ints 100 ;
  lin
    Zero     = mkNat 0 ;
    Succ nat = mkNat (myPlus1 ! nat.n) ;
    Even nat = mkS (mkCl nat.s (mkA "even")) ;
    And p q  = mkS and_Conj p q ;
  oper
    mkNat : MyInts -> Nat ;
    mkNat i = lin Nat {s = symb (showNat ! i) ; n = i} ;

    myPlus1 : MyInts => MyInts = table {
      100 => 100 ;
      n => Predef.plus n 1
      } ;

    showNat : MyInts => Str ;
    showNat = table {
      0 => "0" ; 1 => "1" ; 2 => "2" ;
      3 => "3" ; 4 => "4" ; 5 => "5" ;
      6 => "6" ; 7 => "7" ; 8 => "8" ;
      9 => "9" ; 10 => "10" ; 11 => "11" ;
      12 => "12" ; 13 => "13" ; 14 => "14" ;
      15 => "15" ; 16 => "16" ; 17 => "17" ;
      18 => "18" ; 19 => "19" ; 20 => "20" ;
      _ => "Too big number, I can't be bothered"
      } ;
} ;
```

Let's test in the GF shell:

```
Arithm> gr | l -treebank
Arithm: Even (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))))))))))
ArithmEng: 12 is even
```

So yes, technically it works, but it's unsatisfactory. It only works for a finite `n`, and I had to type out a bunch of boilerplate in the `showNat` oper. I'm still unsure if this was the intended way by the GF book, or if GF used to support more operations on Int.

#### Other solutions

Here's a [solution by daherb](https://github.com/daherb/mulle-spatial/blob/master/grammar/SpatialHTML.gf#L9-L10), where `Zero` outputs the string `"0"` and `Succ` outputs the string `"+1"`, and the final output is evaluated in an external programming language.